# I get "cannot be resolved by type" when using an instance, but not when using a static in same class

Tags: java

Hi programmers out there! My "average" progam work fine when i use a static method inside my class, however when i want to replace my static method and put it in a new class I get an error that says that "average cannot be resolved by type". Don't really know what that means and how i should tackle it.

Here is my working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pig {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(average(54,5,8,9,1));            

    }
    public static int average(int...numbers){
        int total = 0;

        for (int x: numbers){
            total +=x;


        }
        return total/numbers.length;
    }
}
```

---

### If I use an instance it looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pig {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        average avgObj = new average();
        System.out.println(avgObj.averages(54,5,8,9,1));


    }
}
```

---

### my class that this main is calling looks like this:

```
 public class average {
      public int averages(int...numbers){
            int total = 0;

            for (int x: numbers){
                total +=x;
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            return total/numbers.length;
       }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like the compiler can't find your class. What package is it in? (Note that it would also be a good idea to follow Java naming conventions, where class names are in PascalCase.)

Comment: Post complete error messages; they usually say exactly where the problem is. Additionally, Java convention is to start class names with capital letters. This isn't a technical requirement, but it makes reading your code easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import average class in class containing main method.

```
import XXXX.average;

public class pig {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the import statement for your `average` class in the `pig` class.

```
import your.pack.average;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pig {
```

Answer (score 0):

change average to non-public class and write in the bottom of pig.java

if this works, means your running command is wrong.